# Android Drawer Navigation with a ListView, need explanation

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, swipe-gesture

I have implemented a basic Navigation Drawer.

I understand Android Drawer Navigation utilizes Fragment (Nav1 opens Frag1, Nav3 opens Frag3).

I want to achieve Frag1 (or the Home Activity) as a list (i.e., ListFragment) And, when an object on the list is clicked it will take me to Frag4....Frag10 depending on what is clicked.

In another term,

1. Drawer Menu (Nav1...Nav3)
2. Home Activity (Could be Frag1) is a list and a swipe tab  << This is where I am stuck.
3. Other Activities are Swipe tabs too...

Any suggestion, close example?
Thanks

Comment: post the code in your 2. step

Comment: Please  put some codes on your question

Comment: Hello @Rod_Algonquin and NenMa, thanks for your time. My issues is with the theory/how to-not with code, at least now. I am sure you have seen gmail app. 1. It has a drawer-where you can access setting. 2. It has "inbox" - which is like a list. 3. Then you have individual emails. ... I want to make something similar. Possible?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have found the answer, a very simple solution. Create ListFragment class. And in the main class just receive the list!

I have taken help from [ListFragment](http://v4all123.blogspot.ie/2013/07/simple-listfragment-example-in-android.html)